# How can I create events for different LinkedIn users using the LinkedIn API?

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api

Linkedin API: is there a way to create event through the api?

I am trying to use the linkedin  api for different linkedin users create events for theirs accounts.  I read the documentation but I just found about retrieve events and it was under Community Management API(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations/events?view=li-lms-2023-05&tabs=http), my impression is that it will only create events for my organization and not others. Even so, i could not find a create flow on it.

I tried to use old endpoints like "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/eventActions?action=registerEvent", but it does not exist anymore. I tried to POST to https://api.linkedin.com/rest/events but it got 404 - "RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND".